# Why can't I center this div using margin:auto?

Tags: css

The first thing google pulled up was

```
margin:auto
```

which I tried and it did not work.

Using the inspector it appears that one of the sub-elements is taking up the whole width of the containing div.

I think this might be the problem.  Which makes me ask how can I stop this sub-element from taking up all this width that it is not using.

Here is some code that might be relevant:

```
<style>
#pub_fm{
  margin: auto;
}
#pub_fm_tags{
  position:  relative;
  width:  370px;
}
#pub_fm_foo{
  margin-top:10px;
  position:  relative;
  clear:  both;
}
#pub_fm_space{
  height:  10px;
  clear:  both;
}
</style>

    <div id='body_public'>
      <div id = 'pub_fm'>
        <div id = 'pub_fm_tags'></div>
        <div id = 'pub_fm_space'></div>
        <div id = 'pub_fm_arcmarks'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Some actual code would be nice

Comment: The container on your screenshot seems to be centered, doesn’t it? You could further decrease its `width` to see it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to have a `width` attribute set on the element in order for `margin: 0 auto;` to work.

So add:

```
#pub_fm{
  width: 1000px; // Set the width you want
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It even works for `width: auto;` and percentage widths `width: 75%;`:

```
#pub_fm{
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#pub_fm{
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @cadegalt What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: You can use a percentage `width: 75%`

Comment: @cadegalt You can define the width to be auto. Check updated answer.

Comment: @cadegalt It will allow it to expand with its content. If you want a minimum width also you can define a min-width property as well.

Comment: @cadegalt Based on your image, what do you want? In the image it's already centered?

Comment: @cadegalt That doesn't answer my question, I don't understand what you want to happen.

Comment: @cadegalt I didn't even find that element in the link you posted. My answer already has a fixed value, both in px and %, as well as a width: auto solution. So you can go ahead and mark it.